# Get Most Popular Questions of a Tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I was trying to get the most popular questions of all time on a tag `postgresql`. But it seems the tag is been ignored.

Here is the link of that filter  https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=popular&show=alltime&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=postgresql,

Also attached a screenshot of that.

Is it a desired result or a bug?
I am using the new navigation of SO

> [image]

Comment: If you sort by votes, it works correctly. It just does not work if you sort by "hot", so yes, i'd say its a missing feature.

Comment: This is by design.

Comment: @TravisJ you mean this is how the filter is supposed to work?

Comment: I looked through the 54 posts on MSE for the exact reply there but couldn't find it and after a decent amount of time digging stopped. Sometimes moderator replies come in obscure places.

Comment: But basically the response was that the complexity involved in the "hot" metric does not meld well with tag filtering and would require too much time for the query to execute if the tag filtering were to be used there. As a result of the level of complexity involved in both implementing the feature and time for the query to execute, and also because "hot" and by votes were very similar in tag, it will not be done and no plans for it to be done in the future have been made.

Comment: So won't it better to remove that option.

Comment: Also the "hot" is the default option when i click the 'popular' tab. If its sorted by "votes" by default it will be more appropriate..

Comment: Link broken now.